# How do I scan a barcode using ARKit and RealityKit?

Tags: swift, arkit, barcode, barcode-scanner, realitykit

I am building an `IOS` app using `ARKit`, I would like to read a Barcode within `ARView` or through image recognition technique.
For now I have not yet found a tutorial/documentation on it.

Any advice/guidance on doing this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.